# Set Specific Range on X-Axis in HighCharts

Tags: ios, objective-c, highcharts

I am following This Charts Demo : 
[HighCharts](https://www.highcharts.com/ios/demo/line-basic)

I want to set specific Range on X-axis like this

range(dynamic):

```
["04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","00","01","02","03","04" ].
```

[image]
What I am noticing it is taking values automatically based on starting point. How can i set specific range?

Comment: why in array values from 04 to 23 and then from 00 and end 04, is this x axis values you need. If so post the image you want

Comment: Its some timestamp I am getting in JSON.Image wrt to Web representation is updated in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, This issue could be resolved like this :

```
HIXAxis *xaxis = [[HIXAxis alloc]init];
xaxis.categories = Range;
xaxis.categories = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"04",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"00",@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04", nil];
```

Also xaxis needed to be added to options.

Answer (score 0):

You can use categorized xAxis, for example:

```
xAxis.categories = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"04",@"05",@"06",@"07",@"08",@"09",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"00",@"01",@"02",@"03",@"04", nil];
```